# Implementing an efficient image class

Tags: c#, image

I have a design question...

I want to create my own image class called EfficientImage which will include a Load which will take a System.Drawing.Bitmap and use lock bits to convert it into a 2D byte array.

```
class EfficientImage
{

    private byte[,] image;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Load(System.Drawing.Bitmap inImage)
    {
    }

    //etc...

}
```

so i might have

```
EfficentImage ef = new EfficientImage();
ef.Load(myBitmap);
```

What is the best way to access the image array within the object without losing the performance gain of using LockBits in the first place? I believe having an accessor or a property would be replicating the GetPixel/SetPixel in a normal Bitmap object which is not efficient and setting the image field to public would break encapsulation

It may be that this design is entirely the wrong way to go but I would be very pleased to learn of a better/correct way.

Thanks for your help

Comment: just curious, what inefficiencies in existing Image classes are you solving in your proposed class? Or is this just a learning exercise?

Comment: More of a learning exercise to be honest and also so I can apply anything I learn to other problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to apply some kind of filter to images, or have some other kind of processing that modifies multiple pixels.

If that is the case, I would call your class something like `ImageFilter`, for instance:

```
public abstract class ImageFilter
{
    protected abstract void ApplyFilter(byte[,] imageData);

    public Bitmap Apply(Bitmap image)
    {
        // lockbits etc
        ApplyFilter(imageData);
        // unlockbits
    }
}

public class MyFilter : ImageFilter
{
    protected override ApplyFilter(byte[,] imageData)
    {
        // work on the bits
    }
}

Bitmap newBitmap = new MyFilter().Apply(oldBitmap);
```

That way you can write custom filters that deal with the raw data only, while the `ImageFilter` abstract class deals with loading the image and its data.

Apologies if I missed the point :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really like this, however the situation I have is that I'm creating the Image object from a Form class so I wouldn't be able to inherit the Image base class. Can you think of any way around that ?

Comment: The filters (like `MyFilter`) that inherit from `ImageFilter` are new classes you create, and from within the `Form` you can create a new instance of such a filter and `Apply()` it to any `Image` you come across.

Comment: Yes makes sense sorry. Thanks for your help!